# How to store and load instantiated object in react redux?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I am having issue with redux-persist. I have a class object Employee that holds different functions and some private variables. After I pass and restore from redux-persist it only throws back Object but with no type Employee. How do I persist the object with its type as well so that when i retrieve i can use it as Employee object.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is **"you can't"**.  A class instance is non-serializable.  Redux-persist serializes the state for storage by converting it to a JSON `string`.  Anything that is lost when converting to and from a `string` should not be included in the Redux store.

You want to just store the raw data properties of the `Employee` in Redux and use that to construct an `Employee` instance where you need one.